# Best approach to Retrofit all JS files for replacing <myArrayObj>.forEach(iteratorFn) with _.each(<myArrayObj>, iteratorFn)

Tags: javascript, php, regex, node.js, foreach

Best approach to Retrofit all JS files for replacing `<myArrayObj>.forEach(iteratorFn)` with `_.each(<myArrayObj>, iteratorFn)`

I have couple of legacy JS files, which I need to retrofit to support cross-browser web-based application ( specifically for IE8 support)

For that, I need to replace many of the methods, by providing an altogether different signature

### For e.g:-

`myArrayObj.forEach(function(myObj){//do something}, this);`

To:

`_.each(myArrayObj, function(myObj){//do something}, this);`

Similarly I need to replace some(not all) of the below methods as well, which are not supported natively by IE8.
(
For e.g some of the ES5 Features :-

```
Object: keys
Array: isArray
Array.prototype: forEach, map, filter, every, some, reduce, reduceRight, indexOf, lastIndexOf
Date: now
Date.prototype: toISOString, toJSON
Function.prototype: bind
String.prototype: trim
```

)
to equivalent APIs in underscore libraries.

I am not good with regular expressions, and I also tried npm grasp utility(npm install -g grasp), however facing some issues at run-time in replacement.

Any suggestion/comment is very much appreciated, if someone can suggest a sample expression or a better way to do a replacement.

Comment: so what does this have to do with Javascript etc?  You arent running JS.  You are just needing an app that will replace all occurances of X in a File Tree with extension of .js

Comment: @Fallrenreaper. Thanks for responding. For designtime change there is no dependency. However the intention was that this executes in js world( in some js file), which would be a bootstrap file, before the regular runtime flows are called, so that we do this change on the fly, and control it as part of js code, because this retrofit is not permanent and subject to change, based on feedback. So rather than having retroffited files, I prefer to have script logic for retroffiting, which can be changed per needs, until build stablizies. Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Probably a simple
find:  `(\w+)\.forEach\(`
replace: `_.each($1,`

Comment: Thanks for your quick suggestion. That worked well, I slightly modified the searchFilter expression to cover cases for spaces as:- (\S+(.*))\.forEach\(.  I tried this in sublime and worked fine. By any chance, you know how do i make this work with reg expression code ( for e.g new Regex) , so that i can make it work without editor and as part of a script deliverable.